# Cas server and web service authentication (service ticket)

Tags: java, spring-security, restful-authentication, jasig

We are trying to implement authentication through cas server on restful services.

We understood how it should work with documentation but we didn't figure out what happen with the ticket parameter on our called web services.

Using cas server services we are getting a Ticket Granting Ticket (TGT-XXX) and a ticket parameter : the Service Ticket (ST-XXX). Nothing happen when we are using this parameter `<base_url>?ticket=ST-XXX`.

Is there any specific configuration to set up to handle this ticket parameter?

We are using spring-security-cas:5.1.5 (which includes org.jasig.cas:cas-client-core:3.5.1) and cas server 5.3.X and our web application is working well with cas authentication on the website case.